# How can I compose functions when the input is needed to build the pipeline?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm attempting to learn some functional programming in javascript using the [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) library and I keep running into situations where I compose a bunch of functions and then have to pass the input to the result twice.  The following, working code is an example:

```
const search = R.invoker(1, 'search');
const substring = R.invoker(2, 'substring');
const lSplit = (pat, s) => R.compose(substring(0), search(pat))(s)(s);
lSplit(/ /, 'foo bar');
```

`lSplit` takes a regex and a string, locates the first match in the string, and returns everything to the left of the match. The last line evaluates to 'foo'.  It is necessary to pass `s` to the composed function twice: first to find the pattern and build the substring function and then a second time to run the composed function on the string.  The code works, but the `(s)(s)` seems inelegant.

I wrote a function called `twice` that tidies things up a bit but doesn't really address the inelegance:

```
const search = R.invoker(1, 'search');
const substring = R.invoker(2, 'substring');
const twice = f => d => f(d)(d);
const lSplit = pat => twice(R.compose(substring(0), search(pat)));

lSplit(/ /)('foo bar');
```

Is there a cleaner or more elegant way to handle situations where you need to use your data to build your pipeline before feeding it into the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your composition seems messy is because you're composing a binary function `search` with a ternary function `substring`. To make matters worse, the "piped" argument takes place in the middle of the ternary function

```
               _ search(/ /, s)
              /
substring(0, /, s)
```

Instead of worrying about being point free, I would just write the function that expresses it best

```
const lSplit = (pat, s) => substring(0, search(pat,s), s);
```

It's not clever, but it's readable. My recommendation is to let done be done.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I'm still trying to figure out what the "right" way is to write functional code (not that there really is actually such a thing).  And I got a little hung up on being point free.  Your way is a lot more readable.

Comment: Agreed.  Ramda has some clever functions such as `useWith` and `converge`, and Sanctuary exposes additional ones such as `meld` and the `S`-combinator.  These are occasionally very useful and very readable, but too often they **reduce** readability and should be skipped.